# Searching Twitter - authenticating with a Bearer token in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter

After getting a bearer token from twitter on the server side, I pass this to the clients browser to try and use it for a twitter search directly from the browser but it doesn't work, I get 401 unauthorized.
Does twitter allow you to use a bearer token for searching?
I have:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Basic " + Bearertoken;

$resource("http://search.twitter.com/search.json",
                { callback: "JSON_CALLBACK" },
                { get: { method: "JSONP" }});
```

Later I call this with my search term and get the 401.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the word 'Basic' to 'Bearer' and see if it fixes the problem.

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer " + Bearertoken;
```

Comment: Thanks, but no such luck, same 401 response